# $m,n>1$ are relatively prime integers , then are there at-least four idempotent (w.r.t. multiplication) elements in $\mathbb Z_{mn}$ ?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ring-theory

If $m,n>1$ are integers such that $g.c.d.(m,n)=1$ then is it true that there are at-least four elements in $\mathbb Z_{mn}$ such that $x^2=x$ ( i.e. idempotent ) ?

Comment: Do you know the Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: yes ...

Comment: In general, given two rings $R$ and $S$ (with units), can you find at least $4$ distinct idempotents in $R\times S$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Chinese remainder theorem, $\Bbb Z_{mn}$ has the same structure as
$\Bbb Z_{m}\times \Bbb Z_{n}$.

In this algebraic structure,  there are the idempotents:
$$
(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)
$$